# Does WCFStorm support calling WCF services that have JSON enabled?

Tags: wcf, json, webhttpbinding

We have WCF services with JSON enabled and are having issues using WCFStorm calling those services.  If we turn JSON off, then we do not receive the errors.  The error that we receive is below.  We have found something to do with WSHTTPBinding.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

We've found that WcfStorm will not work because It does not support WebHttpBinding.  http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=19&mid=26&ItemID=2&thread=59&pagenumber=1.

Does anyone know how to make it work?  As we like using it.

Or are there any suggestions of other tools that will allow for testing SOAP and JSON as well as allow performance testing and saving scripts?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty certain wcfstorm does not support that binding, and not sure when it will.  And tools for Visual Studio 2010 only support the default datacontract serializer, maybe look here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a late update but as this question pops up on google...

WcfStorm does not support JSON but WcfStorm REST does.
http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/learn-more-rest.aspx

As for Chrome plugins: Postman is a REST client.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm

SOAP UI does both SOAP and JSON/REST in the same application, if you need that. 
http://www.soapui.org

As far as I know, all of them support saving scripts, not sure if WcfStorm REST or Postman supports load/stress testing, but SOAP UI does.